# Does "new char[]" need to be release resources manually?

Tags: c++

For this:
`m_sFilename = new char [len+1];`

Should I call `delete[] m_sFilename;` sometime?

And:

should I use `delete[] m_sFilename` or `delete m_sFilename;`?

Comment: In a precise sense, no, you don't need to; you probably should, if you can; the result of a failure to do so could range from completely benign behavior to a crash-inducing memory leak.

Comment: What kind of horrible C++ language book are you using?  Get another one.

Comment: Sometime? Why would you call some function sometime and not at other times?

Comment: @Jaywalker: By "sometime" he means "at some point".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does "new char[]" need to be release resouces manually?

Yes.

> For this: `m_sFilename = new char [len+1];`
>   Should I call `delete[] m_sFilename;` sometime?

Yes.

> Should I use `delete[] m_sFilename` or `delete m_sFilename;`?

`delete[]`.

---

But you should **actually** use `std::string`, which does all this for you, and is free.

Comment: While the suggestion to use `std::string` is correct but I believe its misplaced. Shouldn't one first learn to use `new[]` and `delete[]` practically instead of hiding behind `std::string`?

Comment: @Jaywalker: Not with `char`. And, going further, one might even say that `std::vector` and `std::string` should be learned _before_ going into details like arrays and dynamic allocation. Unfortunately, for historical reasons, C++ is pretty much never taught this way.

Comment: @Jaywalker - The first thing that you would have to do with `new[]` and `delete[]` is to rewrite the equivalent of `std::string`. On their own they are plain unsafe.

Comment: I knew some students who were taught std::string before char[], and I think they tend to rely on the standard library more (I approve) and had way more interesting homework assignments.

Comment: I agree on the benefits of teaching STL, but no matter how dangerous they are, `new[]` and `delete[]` are an important part of the language. You can't hide it from students forever :/

Comment: @Stargazer712: Nobody said you should.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you don't want the memory allocated by the `new[]` to leak, you should `delete[]` it when you're done using that memory.

To avoid having to keep track of that memory, I recommend you use `std::string` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: *Nitpick* not calling `delete[]` for a pointer allocated with `new[]` technically causes an **Undefined Behavior**, which most likely results in an **Memory Leak** in this case.

Comment: @Als: Where's it stated that it's UB? If you're thinking of n3290 `3.8/4`, "[..] however, if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a delete-expression (5.3.5) is not used to release the storage, the destructor shall not be implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.", then I don't think that this applies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but use `std::string` to store `m_sFilename` instead - it's better in just about every way.

Answer (score 0):

For native data types, and user-defined data types not having destructors using `delete` or `delete[]` would mean the same. The underlying heap manager would free all of the memory. But calling scaler `delete` over a vector new (`new[]`) will not make all destructors to be called. Destructor will be called only once for the very first object.

The behavior given above is compiler/heap-manager (which is handling `new` and `delete`) dependent. For better portability use scaler delete for scaler new and vector delete (`delete[]`) for vector `new`.